Surface Pro keeps draining battery and overheating when shut down
My Surface, dualbooted with Windows, runs Ubuntu from live USB. For some reason, my computer would not stop draining the battery and getting itself hot when it's shut down. This doesn't happen when the computer is in suspense, or in Windows. When I was sleeping, I heard my computer heat up and I thought it was the wind.
For context, I was unable to boot the linux-surface kernel because of the error "you need to boot the kernel first." I also installed TLP to save the battery (which the built-in battery saver in Ubuntu actually drains the battery).
Is anyone able to provide a solution or at least a cause?
